# Change self bot's nickname in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to change the **bot's nickname (not the username!)** when it's ready/online.

I've tried using `client.user.setNickname('sup')` and `client.user.id.setNickname('sup')` but doesn't work.

I saw a lot of answer telling to use `message.guild.members.find(client.user.id).setNickname('sup')` but **I don't want to use it when a message is sent but instantly when it's online** using `client.once("ready", () => {})`

Answer (score 1):

`client.user` doesn't have a `setNickname()` method as users don't have `nickname`s only guild members have. However, you can get the guild's [`me`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=me) property (it's the client user as a GuildMember of the guild) and set the nickname on them.

You can get the guild by its ID and then use `setNickname()` on `guild.me`:

```js
client.once('ready', async () => {
  console.log('Bot is connected...');

  const GUILD_ID = '630136153921670528';
  const guild = await client.guilds.fetch(GUILD_ID);

  guild.me.setNickname('NICKNAME');
});
```

Comment: i tried combining it with     `for (i in guildsID) { const guild = await client.guilds.fetch(i); guild.me.setNickname('sup'); }`

but it doesn't work (guildsID is `[]`)

Comment: to get guildsID i used: `const guildsID = client.guilds.cache.map(guild => guild.id);`

Comment: With `for...in` the `i` will be the index (0, 1, etc). You should use `for...of` loop and not `for...in` with arrays. Try `for (let i of guildsID) { ...`

Comment: i tried it but it doesn't work, the problem is that guildsID does not contains all guilds's id

Comment: That's strange. I just checked it and it does work for me as expected. How many servers is your bot on?

Comment: As you are using a SelfBot, your Discord.JS version might not behave as you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Get the guild via id. ie .guilds.cache.get("guild id")

Updating the nickname is simply, just call .me.setNickname("new nickname") - it'll error if it doesn't have enough permissions.