# Discord.js Changing Nickname and avatar continuously

Tags: discord, discord.js, chatbot

I want to change my bot's nickname which do not need to put in some thing like `client.on("ready" or "message"`

So far I've tried:

- `client.user.setNickname()`
- `client.setNickname()`

I've seen someone having a bot which changes its avatar and nickname continuously and I have no idea about their algorithm. (When I click the bot to view its profile it didn’t display anything)

If you want to have a look at the bot: https://discord.gg/pz8S2hrRnf
#server-bridge

Comment: So where do you want to change it if not in an event listener? You can use `guild.me.setNickname()`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66244192/6126373

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the nickname on the user property, but you can on a [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember).

As [@Zsolt Meszaros](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6126373/zsolt-meszaros) said, you would have to use `<Guild>.me.setNickname()`

See more details at the docs [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=setNickname).